# visa fee refund

Tags: uk, fees-and-charges

I wonder if you can advise me whether I can get a refund on my family visa fees.
I hold ILR under tier 2 scheme and applied for my family (3 persons) visa under PBS Dependant visa. They charged every individual fee for 5 years but only issued visa for 3 years. Fee for 5 years is £1408 per person and for 3 years is £704 per person. As the application was made online, I had to submit fee for 5 years as it didn't give me any option to select 3 year visa.

Can I apply for a refund and where to send the request.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Kind Regards
Aqeel ashraf

Comment: This will probably be migrated to [Expatriates.SE], since it's off topic for [Travel.SE].  You can link your account here to your account there, in which case you ought to be able to retain ownership of the question (allowing you to post comments, for example, before you have acquired sufficient reputation to comment on others' questions and answers).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have applied for the wrong duration of the visa, and in cases like this the result is usually that they approve the application for the correct duration but keep the application fee.

The [guidance (pdf)](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/791595/SWS_Dependant_Guidance_03-2019.pdf) says

> **Periods of grant**
>
> 45. Partners: We will grant leave in line with the expiry date of the Main Applicant’s leave, except where the Main Applicant has been granted indefinite leave to remain. In these cases, we will grant you a period of three years leave. An application for further leave may then be made if required to take you up to the applicable qualifying period for indefinite leave to remain.
> 46. Children: We will grant leave in line with:
>     (i) a period which expires on the same day as the leave granted to the parent whose
>     leave expires first, or
>     (ii) Where both parents have, or are at the same time being granted, indefinite leave to
>     remain, or have since become British  citizens, leave to remain will be granted to the
>     applicant for a period of 3 years.

If the online application portal did not allow you to make an application for a three year visa then you can [submit a complaint to UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration/about/complaints-procedure), but I suppose it's unlikely that they will refund the money; they will more likely argue that you should have made the complaint before paying the fee.

Following UK immigration news in the media, I see that some people have had some luck by involving their MP.  If I were you, and the response to the complaint proves unsatisfactory, I would try that.